# Why ECS pipeline needed Task Definition while Service already have the task definition assigned in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops, amazon-ecs, bitbucket-pipelines

on bitbucket, the config is required to use both 'service' and 'task definition', I think this is redundant because the service already assigned with task definition, or we have an explanation?

[image]

```
// https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-ecs-deploy/src/1.2.0/README.md
  - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecs-deploy:1.2.0
    variables:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1'
      CLUSTER_NAME: 'my-ecs-cluster'
      SERVICE_NAME: 'my-ecs-service'
      TASK_DEFINITION: 'task-definition.json'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task definition in ECS service you are showing is probably the initial deployment. When you do subsequent deployments you **update the task definition** with new image version, or extra parameters. You can't update ECS task without providing task definition.

The task definition is thus required. It's same if you use **CodeDeploy** to deploy to ECS - task definition must be provided:

-[AppSpec 'resources' section for Amazon ECS deployments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-resources.html#reference-appspec-file-structure-resources-ecs)

> TaskDefinition – **Required**. This is the task definition for the Amazon ECS service to deploy.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that ecs-deploy pipeline is just simulating "pull latest docker image and redeploy with same task-definition", turns out it is more complex